# Google Cloud Speech-to-text API adding a phrase set in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I'm currently using google cloud's speech-to-text api to transcribe a long audio file. I've managed to set it up to do this by writing a python script, but I want to add a custom phrase set to improve the trancription results, as described in their documentation https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation

I have a list of the phrases I want to add, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work in python.

This is my current code:

```
def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri, phrases):
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""

    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=44100,
        language_code="en-US",
        use_enhanced=True,
        model="video",
        enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
        audio_channel_count=2,
        speech_context = speech.SpeechContext(phrases=phrases)
    )

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result(timeout=20000)

    transcript = []
    confidence_ints = []
    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print("Confidence: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
        transcript.append(str(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        confidence_ints.append(float(result.alternatives[0].confidence))

    return transcript, confidence_ints
```

Everything works until I try to add the phrases using the speech_context argument. Please help!